# AutoComplate textbox in mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a model that has relation with another model.

```
   public class TurnRatings
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Referred")]
    public int ReferredId { get; set; }
    public virtual Referred Referred { get; set; }
 }

  public class Referred 
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public string Family { get; set; }
 }
```

I want add a view for TurnRatings. I want add a autocomplate textbox for show Referred .

in view.

```
 <div class="form-group">
 @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ReferredId, new { @class = "control-label col-lg-1" })
 <div class="col-lg-3">
   @Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.ReferredId)
   @Html.TextBox("Referred")
   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ReferredId)
 </div>
 </div>
```

and jquery

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        var url = '@Url.Action("ListReferred", "TurnRatings")';
        $('#Referred').autocomplete({
            source: function(request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    data: { query: request.term },
                    dataType: 'json',
                    type: 'GET',
                    success: function(data) {
                        response($.map(data,
                            function(item) {
                                return {
                                    family: item.Family,
                                    id: item.Id
                                }
                            }));
                    }
                });
            },
            select:
                function(event, ui) {
                    $('#ReferredId').val(ui.item.id);
                    $('#Referred').val(ui.item.family);
                    return false;
                },
            minLength: 1
        });
    });
```

and Controller

```
  public JsonResult ListReferred(string term)
    {
        var list = _db.Referreds.Where(m => m.Family.Contains(term));
        return Json(list, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

but don't send term value for controller.(send null)

my question is : 
Is it a good solution?
Why do't send data for controller?

Comment: Your passing `{ query: request.term }` but your parameter name is `term`.

Comment: how do passing the parameter?

Comment: Change the script to `{term: request.term }` (or the controller method to `ListReferred(string query)`)

Comment: Thanks a lot :) , but don't add items to <ul> !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your key is wrong.You must write query in action parameters.
Controller

```
public JsonResult SearcAnything(string term)
    {
        return Json(data.Where(s => s.Name.Contains(term)), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Client

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            jQuery('#Referred').autocomplete({
                source: function (request, response) {
                    jQuery.ajax({
                        url: '@Url.Action("SearcAnything","Home")',
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: {
                            term: request.term
                        },
                        success: function (data) {
                            response(data);
                        }
                    });
                },
                minLength: 3
            });

        });
```